# Converting 14 digit date string into DateTime (SQL Server)

Tags: datetime

I'm trying to parse a text file date string into a C# DateTime which is then inserted into SQL Server.

I keep receiving this error:

> Error: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999
>    11:59:59 PM.

I'm guessing it doesn't like the YYYY-MM-DD format?
My data type in SQL is datetime2(7)

And the string I want to convert is in this format:

20121030123010

(2012-10-30 12:30:10)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a default value from SQL Server GETDATE()

Comment: Hello Michael,  Can you explain your answer here in detail ? I have a situation to convert 14 digit bigint to datetime datatype